# Scroll outer scrollview, then scroll the inner

Tags: ios

I have a view that looks like below:

- Outer UIScrollview

  - UIImageView
  - Inner UICollectionView

[image]

I would like when the user scrolls, it should reach the end of the outer scrollview and the starts scrolling the inner scrollview, and vice versa(when the user scrolls up, he reaches the top of the inner scrollview and then starts scrolling the outer view).

All this is neccessary to be smooth. By smooth, I mean that user is able to start decelerating from the outer scrollview, and then the deceleration is moved within the innerview.

I hope I was clear, since it is not so easy to explain. I am sorry if such question already exists, but I couldn't find exactly the same. I would appreciate a link and/or example.

Thanks in advance for your help :)

EDIT: I wouldn't like to do it with a single collection view with a header view, containing the image, for reasons, not mentioned here. So I wouldn't like to use any approach, which is using a header cell.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use a header view? What is the effect you are trying to achieve? Maybe it can be done in an easier way.

Comment: I would like to do something like Instagram's Profile tab. The User should be able to switch between several collection views, while the image remains. Also, every collection view has its own collection view controller and it's own layout.

Comment: Unfortunately these answers don't seem to solve your problem, and I have the EXACT same question. Any progress?

Comment: Did you find a way to do the instagram-like scrolling with the collection view? I'm trying to do something similar as well.

Comment: I found a way, but I wouldn't recommend it. I just place a header view behind the image, so it's used as a buffer. Then I observed scrollview's contentOffset changes and that way I change header view's height, varying from 0 to image's height. Once again, I don't recommend this approach, since it looks like a workaround to me and the code is ugly. Finally, we changed view controller's appearance, so it doesn't look this way anymore

Answer (score 1):

Give the outer scrollView a `contentSize` that's equal to your image’s size plus your collection view’s contentSize.

Forbid scrolling on the collectionView.

Implement your outer scrollView’s delegate `scrollViewDidScroll` method to update:

- the image’s transform(so that you have the illusion it stays still)
- the collection view’s transform (the same)
- the collection view’s contentOffset (so that you have the illusion you've scroll it, and not the outer scrollView).

Quite a bit difficult to explain like that, especially I'm in a hurry, but it's feasible and that's exactly the way I've done it a few months ago in an app currently in production.

This actually has the effect of "transferring" the inertia from the outer scroll view to the inner collectionView, which is what I think you want.

Answer (score 0):

In your image it looks like you have a `UICollectionView` with a section header view.

It doesn't require any special scroll views or anything. The image at the top is just the section header of the collection view.